# SQL Query Newsletter subscription status with custom tables

Tags: sql, newsletter

I currently have the following script that someone else wrote for me that exports custom Magento data to a CSV file. It takes data from the two tables 'perfume_fragrance' & 'perfume_fragrance_blend' and adds it to the customer's email address.

I would like to add a further column to the CSV file that includes the customer's newsletter subscription status.

I've found the 'newsletter_subscriber' table which has the 'customer_id' and 'subscriber_status' but am not sure how to add it to the SQL query.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

chdir(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "removed", "removed", "removed");

$data = array();
$data[] = array('Email', 'Fragrance', 'Location', 'Date', 'Creator', 'Blend');

$sql = "SELECT CE.*, PF.fragrance_id, PF.fragrance_name, PF.created_at, PF.created_on, PF.created_by FROM customer_entity CE JOIN perfume_fragrance PF ON PF.customer_id = CE.entity_id AND PF.created_at = '- PA EVENT'";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM perfume_fragrance_blend WHERE fragrance_id = ".$row["fragrance_id"];
        $result3 = $db->query($sql3);
        if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
            $blend_desc = '';
            $i = 1;
            while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                $blend_desc .= $row3['blend_name'].' x '.$row3['blend_qty'];
                if($i < $result3->num_rows){ $blend_desc .= ', '; } 
                $i++;                   
            }
            //echo "id: " . $row["entity_id"]. " - Email: " . $row["email"]. " - Fragrance: " . $row["fragrance_name"]. " - Location: " . $row["created_at"]. " - Date: " . $row["created_on"]. " - Creator: " . $row["created_by"]. " - Blend: " . $blend_desc."<br>";
            $data[] = array($row["email"], $row["fragrance_name"], $row["created_at"], $row["created_on"], $row["created_by"], $blend_desc);
        }

    }
}

echo "Beginning CSV Creation...<br />";

$fp = fopen('database.csv', 'w');

foreach ($data as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);

echo "Script Finished";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the `newsletter_subscriber` table on the `customer_id`. I would suggest a left join since there can be customers without newsletter subscriptions.

Replace your 3 lines with the following code (first are CSV header, second is the main SQL statement and third is the csv line):

```
$data[] = array('Email', 'Fragrance', 'Location', 'Date', 'Creator', 'Blend','Status');

$sql = "SELECT CE.*, PF.fragrance_id, PF.fragrance_name, PF.created_at, PF.created_on, PF.created_by, NL.subscriber_status FROM customer_entity CE 
JOIN perfume_fragrance PF ON PF.customer_id = CE.entity_id AND PF.created_at = '- PA EVENT'
LEFT JOIN newsletter_subscriber NL on CE.entity_id = NL.customer_id";


$data[] = array($row["email"], $row["fragrance_name"], $row["created_at"], $row["created_on"], $row["created_by"], $blend_desc, $row["subscriber_status"]);
```